# Does a 2010 VW Jetta S (2.5 L gasoline engine) have a timing belt or chain?

Tags: vw, timing-belt

The questions says it all.  Does a 2010 VW Jetta S (2.5 L gasoline engine) have a timing belt or chain?  Please reference where you got this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a chain. There are two, as the matter of fact, upper and lower. Relevant parts (chains, tensioners, guide rails) can be purchased [individually](http://www.germanautoparts.com/Volkswagen/Jetta/Engine/227/11) or [as a kit](http://www.germanautoparts.com/Volkswagen/Jetta/Engine/274/6).

For future reference, indication of that could be found in owner’s manual. Chains usually do not require maintenance, whereas belt replacement would be noted on in maintenance schedule somewhere around 150-200k km (100-125k miles).

Comment: My manual did not have a maintenance schedule that came with it, I had to download one from the Internet that was general for all 2010 model VW's, some of which require timing belt replacements, so it wasn't clear from that.

Comment: Ah, okay. I just seem to remember having it, because my ex bought 2012 certified used 2.5, just cannot confirm now for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

It's a chain. It should be the same as this [2008 2.5L L5 VW engine](http://www.autopartslib.com/2008-volkswagen-jetta-2-5l-engine-cylinder-head-components-parts-diagram/) ... #18:

[image]

Comment: @Joshua ... I realized after the fact I had not put that it was actually a chain, though it did state it in the link I provided. Live and learn.